# How to get Exception OSError 's third arguments?

Tags: python

From [Python document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError):

> For backwards compatibility, if three arguments are passed, the args attribute contains only a 2-tuple of the first two constructor arguments.

So How do we I the third arguments, like the 'invalid path'?

```
try:
    open('invalid path')
except OSError as e:
    error = e
    print(error.args[0],error.args[1])
    print(e)
```

The results:

```
2 No such file or directory
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'invalid path'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same docs:

> For exceptions that involve a file system path (such as open() or
>   os.unlink()), **filename** is the file name passed to the function. For
>   functions that involve two file system paths (such as os.rename()),
>   filename2 corresponds to the second file name passed to the function.

So you simply do `error.filename`, because `filename` is an optional arg which only gets passed for certain types of errors.

To make a one for all check, you can use `hasattr`:

```
if hasattr(error, 'filename'):
    print(error.filename)
```

Comment: True, but the exception object will always have the attributes `filename` and `filename2` (`filename2` exists even if using the `open` function, it is simply set to `None`), so if `hasattr(..)` will always return `True`. Instead, the check should be `if error.filename` or `if error.filename2`.

Comment: @DeepSpace You're right on that. But comes useful when catching a list of Errors in the same block, when the `try` block performs more than just `open`

Comment: print(None) will get a 'None'. So does this mean we should add a line `if error.filename:` before print() will be an ultimate one for all?

Comment: If filename were `None`, then that would not be an `OSError` but a `TypeError`

Comment: From the document:  `exception OSError(errno, strerror[, filename[, winerror[, filename2]]])`. Does this mean filename is possible to be `None`?

Comment: Means it's an optional argument. `errno` and `strerror` are always guaranteed to be passed unlike `filename`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `error.args` contains `(2, 'No such file or directory')`.

In order to get the path, you should access `error.filename`:

```
try:
    open('some/invalid path')
except OSError as e:
    print(e.filename)
    >> 'some/invalid path'
```